# How can I invoke lambda handler in custom runtime environment?

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, graalvm

I built a spring boot 3 application and compiled it with Graal VM. When we use Graal VM, we need to choose a custom runtime on AWS Lambda. I chose Amazon Linux 2023 machine on arm64 architecture as runtime. I created a bootstrap file and zipped my executable with it. When I upload this zip and test my lambda function I see that spring boot starts but since I cannot invoke the handler in my java code, the lambda function doesn't work and give an error.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.1)
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10009.69 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3020.29 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
START RequestId: d043768d-c4b1-4ad0-af1e-586e383db38e Version: $LATEST
2023-12-28T10:16:52.988Z d043768d-c4b1-4ad0-af1e-586e383db38e Task timed out after 3.04 seconds

END RequestId: d043768d-c4b1-4ad0-af1e-586e383db38e
REPORT RequestId: d043768d-c4b1-4ad0-af1e-586e383db38e  Duration: 3041.01 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 38 MB
```

Please note that unlike other environment configurations **there is no option to choose the handler mehtod at the custom runtime configuration**. Otherwise, when I don't use Graal VM, I can run it on AWS Lambda supported environments such as JAVA 17 without a problem.

Additional Files:

bootstrap:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT:-.}
set -euo pipefail
./demo_linux_aws
```

Handler function:

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with custom VMs but the error that you have posted looks like the lambda function isn't setup properly. In the lambda go to General configuration -> timeout. Since Java is known for having a cold start when the lambda is invoked, the default timeout is set to 3 seconds which is why you are getting this error. Setting the timeout according to the application might help you to get it to work. Also additionally you can check the memory that is assigned to the lambda for execution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually, that is not the case since even without graal vm the start up time is sufficent to run the function. But nevertheless, I had tried to set the timeout as 5 minutes, and it just keep running and gives the same error after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using Spring Cloud Function. Spring Cloud Function has an adapter which handles routing with AWS Lambda automaticaly as following.

Add the aws adapter to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add the following property into your applicaiton.properties file.

```
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['function-name']
```

From Aws Lambda send the function name within the header. Spring Cloud Function AWS adapter will handle the rest.

```
{
 "headers": {
 "function-name": "readOrders"
 }
}
```

You can check my medium aritcle for details:
[Medium article to run GraalVM compiled Spring Boot 3 project on AWS Lambda](https://medium.com/@nihatonder87/beat-the-aws-lambda-cold-start-time-with-graalvm-and-spring-boot-3-35aef1da30b9)

Comment: You reckon this approach will work for a rest application?

Comment: AWS Lambda is different from a REST service. It accepts json request, but we can't say that it is REST. On the other hand, instead of Spring Cloud Functions you can publish a Spring REST service with AWS Lambda. In this case, you can send a Rest request which matches with the path, httpMehod and body, but you should handle the routing by yourself since you won't have the spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws dependency for Rest requests. If you don't have to use GraalVM, you can use a java runtime, and in this case AWS will allow you register your handler via the GUI.

Comment: Is this solution working also with the class StreamLambdaHandler from your initial code and Controllers? I see that in the sample you put on github it is not appearing.

Comment: And I have also one more question: how should be handled the routing by yourself in a REST application compiled native with GraalVM? Do you have an example?